# Finding a batch file in salesforce

Tags: batch

I want to know, how to find a batch file in Salesforce? What all are the methods to find a batch file in Salesforce?

Comment: What do you mean by finding a batch file?

Comment: In Salesforce a *batch class* is an Apex class that implements the Database.Batchable interface. When an instance of this class is created and put in the queue awaiting execution this is called a *batch job*. A *batch file* usually refers to a file on a Windows system with the .bat extension that contains a series (or batch) of MS DOS style commands. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a text search on the configuration files looking for "Database.Batchable"

To find the scheduled batch jobs you could perform the following query: SELECT Id, Status, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, numberOfErrors FROM AsyncApexJob

or look in the Apex jobs in Setup

Kind regards,

Rudy De Coninck